# Unable to send email from laravel?

Tags: php, email, ssl, laravel

I'm trying to send email using Laravel. I configured `mail.php` with details of gmail server and used my personal gmail account credentials. It worked fine.

Then i tried to configure `mail.php` with the `Secure SSl/TLS` settings that my mail provider has provided me.

I changed `host, port, username and password`. I also changed `encryption` to `ssl`.

But i'm not able to send email. After some loading time, it just shows a blank page. No Error.

here's my config file(have removed doc-blocks):

```
<?php

return array(    
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'myServerHostAddress',
    'port' => portno,    
    'from' => array('address' => 'registration@gambiadept.com', 'name' => 'Gambia Dept'),
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'usernameFromMyServiceProvider',
    'password' => 'myPassword',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,    
);
```

Comment: Have you looked in the logs for your mail server, web server and laravel itself?

Comment: @Ben Swinburne

There was no entry in the laravel log regarding this. I changed password to a wrong password and tried to send a mail. Log was created with something `Failed to authenticate`. Then i changed my password back to the real one, sent mail. No Error. No Log report

Comment: How about the httpd logs and those on the mailserver?

Comment: I'm on localhost. Where can i find httpd logs and mailserver logs?

Comment: I searched and found `/var/log/apache2/access.log`. Last entry was `127.0.0.1 - - [25/Sep/2014:19:13:50 +0530] "GET /vrvt/public/vehicle HTTP/1.1" 200 740 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22"`

Comment: Can you paste here your config?? without gmail user and password ofc